# How to save variable values of jquery into normal javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have worked with this jquery feature and need help to save the values in jscript from jquery variable values

```
function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: woeid,
    unit: 'c',
```

how do I store location values in a javascript variable ? is it possible to do so  ? if not how may I solve the problem .

Comment: Welcome to SO, why the provided source code is truncated ?

Comment: `var location = "https://sub.domain.abc/path/to/location/is/here.html";`